# Fraction written in a handwriting font

Tags: fonts

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  

\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont}{\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfont}
\begin{align*}
\text{moles of \ce{Fe^{+2}} in 1 L } &= \frac{50.01 \times 10^-{3}}{392.14} \\[\jot]
&= \SI{0.0001275}{\mol}
\end{align*}
\end{myfont}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I make the whole thing look handwritten?

Comment: 10^-{3}  should presumably be 10^{-3}, just use `\text` inside the fraction to pick up the text font there too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean `\text{moles of \ce{Fe^{+2}} in 1 L } &\text{=} \frac{\text{50.01} \times \text{10}^\text{-3}}{\text{392.14}} \\[\jot]
  &\text{=} \text{0.0001275 mol}`?

Comment: \text{moles of \ce{Fe^{+2}} in 1 L } &= \text{ \frac{50.01 \times10^{-3}}{392.14}} That's what I tried, but it throws an error. Did you mean wrap the induvidual numbers with \text{}? That works but the font does not pick the \times up

Comment: @cfr thanks! http://imgur.com/zbimc1L

Comment: I don't suppose that augie has a `\times` symbol, does it?

Comment: @Jack I meant `\text{moles of } \ce...` but I see you have an answer now anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: augie maths]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont}{\par}
\newcommand*{\augietimes}{\mathbin{\text{x}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfont}
\begin{align*}
  \text{moles of \ce{Fe^{+2}} in 1 L } &\text{=} \frac{\text{50.01} \augietimes \text{10}^\text{-3}}{\text{392.14}} \\[\jot]
  &\text{=} \text{0.0001275 mol}
\end{align*}
\end{myfont}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do like such tricks!

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thanks, I think... Do you mean the times symbol?

Comment: Yes! The `\times`, possible because font is sans serif. :-)

Comment: I've rarely seen something as horrible. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg As I've said before, this site does not enforce aesthetic sanity ;).