# Handwritten comments and annotations in margin

Tags: fonts, margins, comments, annotations

Is it possible to typeset handwritten comments and annotations in the margins around a paragraph like in the example below?

What would be the closest approximation of this done in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: For basic margin notes you can use `\marginpar`; the package [marginnote](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote?lang=en) gives improvement.

Comment: Related, perhaps, on the subject of handwriting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm.  Also, these: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195798/using-handwriting-font-in-proofs, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211588/fraction-written-in-a-handwriting-font

Comment: It may help if you can be more precise on what you hope to achieve: the hand written look? The two layers of annotations? The arrows pointing between annotation and text? Allowing text to flow into the header/footer space (and not just the left/right margins)? General annotation with underlining/highlighting? The vertically written text?

Comment: As to how to place things arbitrarily on the page, irrespective of specified margins, there is this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: @WillieWong I want to achieve a page that looks like the example provided or as similar to it as possible.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Combining results from the questions cited in my comments... namely, doncherry's use of the `fts` "Teen Spirit" font (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/teenspirit/) referenced at [How do I make my document look like it was written by a Cthulhu-worshipping madman?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm).  I also used my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page) (adapted for new hook system)

Below, I introduce

```
\handnote[<angle>]{<x from left>}{<y from top>}{<width>}{<color>}{<content>}
```

EDITED to introduce the following supporting emphasis markings:

```
\handline[<thickness-scale>]{<width>}
\handrightarrow[<thickness-scale>]{<width>}
\handleftarrow[<thickness-scale>]{<width>}
\handhookrightarrow[<thickness-scale>]{<width>}
\handhookleftarrow[<thickness-scale>]{<width>}
\handstealthrightarrow[<thickness-scale>]{<width>}
\handstealthleftarrow[<thickness-scale>]{<width>}
\handuparrow[<thickness-scale>]{<height>}
\handdownarrow[<thickness-scale>]{<height>}
```

These emphasis markings appear as macros within the context of a `\handnote`'s `<content>`.  Thus, when they constitute the complete content of a given `\handnote`, they may be freely rotated using the `<angle>` parameter of `\handnote`.  The use of varying `<thickness-scale>`s and `<width>`s allows for repetition of emphasis markings to be avoided.

Also EDITED so that the `<content>` of `\handnote` is now top-aligned to the specified vertical coordinate given by `<y from top>`.

Here is the MWE.  The emphasis markings are summarized on page 2 (EDITED to account for LaTeX kernel changes on 2018.12.1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,stackengine,scalerel,xcolor,emerald,rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(#1,-\dimexpr#2 ){#3}}}
\newcommand\handnote[6][0]{\atxy{#2}{#3}{\rotatebox{#1}{\parbox[t]{#4}{%
  \raggedright\fontfamily{fts}\selectfont\color{#5}#6}}}}
\newcommand\handxform[7]{% SCALING IS EMPLOYED TO EXPAND THE USEFUL RANGE OF #7
  \raisebox{#1}{%
    \scalebox{4}[#6]{% THE 4X SCALING IS LATER COUNTERED BY 0.25
      \raisebox{#2}{%
        \rotatebox{#3}{%
          \stretchto{%
            \rotatebox{#4}{%
              \char#5}%
          }{0.25\dimexpr#7\relax}% THE 0.25 IS COUNTERED BY THE EARLIER 4X SCALING
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand\handline             [2][1]{\handxform{.20ex}{0.30ex}{-90}{ 12}{47}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\handrightarrow       [2][1]{\handxform{.55ex}{0.45ex}{-90}{ 90}{62}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\handleftarrow        [2][1]{\handxform{.55ex}{-0.5ex}{ 90}{ 90}{62}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\handhookrightarrow   [2][1]{\handxform{.70ex}{0.60ex}{-90}{-30}{35}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\handhookleftarrow    [2][1]{\handxform{.50ex}{0.60ex}{-90}{ 30}{36}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\handstealthrightarrow[2][1]{\handxform{.50ex}{-0.2ex}{ 90}{ 80}{60}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\handstealthleftarrow [2][1]{\handxform{.50ex}{0.40ex}{-90}{ 80}{60}{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\handyform[7]{\raisebox{#1}{\scalebox{#6}[1]{%
  \rotatebox{#3}{\stretchto{\rotatebox{#4}{\raisebox{#2}{\char#5}}}{#7}}}}}
\newcommand\handuparrow          [2][1]{\handyform{.10ex}{-.08ex}{  0}{ -0}{91}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\handdownarrow        [2][1]{\handyform{.05ex}{-.00ex}{  0}{ -0}{93}{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!10!orange!10}
\handnote[1]{6.3in}{1.5in}{2in}{red}{\lipsum[4]}
\handnote[4]{0.3in}{4.85in}{1.3in}{blue}{I have a really short comment}
\handnote[4]{1.3in}{4.88in}{1.3in}{blue}{\handrightarrow[1.7]{4ex}}
\handnote[0]{3.8in}{4.82in}{3in}{blue}{%
  \handline[2]{7ex} \handline[2.5]{6ex} \handline[2]{5ex}}%
\handnote[10]{6.2in}{4.8in}{3in}{blue}{\handleftarrow[2]{10ex}}%
\handnote[-75]{5.95in}{9.2in}{1.3in}{red}{\handhookleftarrow[2.1]{6ex}}
\handnote[20]{6.3in}{9.55in}{1.3in}{red}{What is the meaning of life?  
  I really want to know.  Does the teacher even read this?}
\lipsum[1-6]

\lipsum[5-6]
\handnote[89]{.5in}{7in}{7in}{red}{Here is a test of a long vertical note!
  I am thinking it is working just great!}
\handnote[10]{6.5in}{5.8in}{2in}{blue}{\Huge The end!!!!}
\handnote[2]{2.38in}{4.43in}{3in}{blue}{\handline[2]{12ex}}
%
\handnote[0]{2in}{6.0in}{4.9in}{red}{\LARGE{\Huge ACCENTS:}\\%
  handlines: \handline{6ex}\handline[3]{12ex}
  handrightarrows: \handrightarrow{4ex}\handrightarrow[2]{5ex}
  handleftarrows: \handleftarrow{4ex}\handleftarrow[2]{5ex}
  handhookrightarrows: \handhookrightarrow[1]{4ex}\handhookrightarrow[2.1]{7ex}
  handhookleftarrows:\handhookleftarrow[1]{5ex}\handhookleftarrow[2.1]{9ex}
  handstealthleftarrows: \handstealthleftarrow{5ex}\handstealthleftarrow[2]{5ex}
  handstealthrightarrows: \handstealthrightarrow{5ex}\handstealthrightarrow[2]{5ex}
  handuparrows \handuparrow{2ex}\handuparrow[1.2]{4ex}
  handdownarrows \handdownarrow{2ex}\handdownarrow[1.2]{4ex}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

FYI: the Teen Spirit font table is available at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/teenspirit/teenspirit.pdf, on page 2

EDIT Note: The `\handxform` macro has been modified to introduce scaling/counterscaling so as to extend the range of sizes over which the `\handline` mandatory argument (length) may be successfully applied.  The `\handline` macro can now be employed to make lines as long as `\LARGE 47ex` in length without arithmetic overflow.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Is there any way to draw lines and arrows from the text to the comments or between comments?

Comment: @Bartholomaios Not directly, but there is no reason the `<content>` of this call can't be a `\tikzpicture` that does just that.

Comment: This is so cool. It would be perfect if each handnote could be an anchor for a tikzpicture node... 

But thank you, this is great!

Comment: @Bartholomaios Unfortunately, `tikz` is not my speciality.

Comment: "handnote" should be its own package on ctan!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes What is the `fts` font family?

Comment: @NVaughan After more investigation, `fts` is the "code" for the TeenSpirit font at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/teenspirit/

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Cheers!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes could you combine handnotes with [handlatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks) to get a randomized script?

Comment: @Bartholomaios Are you sure you provided the right link?  It seems to go to something with `hyperref`...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you are right. Here the [correct link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134220/realistic-handwritten-document/134223#134223)

Comment: @Bartholomaios --- for arrows, you can use `tikzmark` as in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295903/refer-to-a-node-in-tikz-that-will-be-defined-in-the-future-two-passes, combined with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines

Comment: @Bartholomaios While I can find hand.dtx at https://github.com/markwgirard/handlatex/blob/master/hand.dtx, I am unable to find the ins file to extract the sty file from it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it's in this tarball: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/handlatex/handlatex-1.0.0.tar.bz2

Comment: @Bartholomaios I have revised my answer to provide easier use of realistic hand-drawn emphasis markings like lines and arrows.

Comment: How would one modify  this to use XeLatex and any font using the fontspec package?

Comment: @ramonskovitch Removing the `\fontfamily{fts}\selectfont` from the `\handnote` macro allows it to be compiled in  `xelatex` (but using the base font in the comments).  I'd have to think further on the xelatex syntax for changing the font at that point in the code.

Comment: @ramonskovitch  In the preamble, `\usepackage{fontspec}`, and in place of `\fontfamily{fts}\selectfont` replace it with, for example, `\setmainfont{Calibri}`.  Note that all the annotation markings, will have to be revised, or also set in the `Teen Spirit` font.

Comment: @Bartholomaios See also my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320033/how-i-can-customize-the-fill-and-line-in-tikz/320113#320113.  Note that while the macros have the same names, they have been revised a bit.  Also double-stealth arrow and box function added.