# How to produce handwritten arrows?

Tags: arrows

In the article [*Topologies et Faisceaux* by **Demazure**](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.polo/SGA3/Exp4-23mai11.pdf), one can find the following arrows (well, it is not in the link, but in the book version):

[image: photo of arrows]

And, out of pure curiosity, I am wondering if it is possible to reproduce this effect in (La)TeX? I think this kind of *hand-written* arrows are quite fun to read. :)

I don't know if an MWE is needed; I have no clue how to produce this sort of things in TeX at present.

Thanks for any help or reference.

Comment: They are actually handwritten. From times when technology wasn't that advanced.

Comment: Thanks for the response. And I want to know how to produce the *hand-written* arrows like that. :-D I think it would be fun to code such arrows out. :)

Comment: Maybe a task for a very rainy Sunday afternoon; some random variation of a path in Metapost. The simplest way is scanning and tracing a few of them.

Comment: The Teen Spirit (`fts`) font.  See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317190/handwritten-comments-and-annotations-in-margin/317195#317195

Comment: Related: [Create xkcd style diagram in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74878/11002)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for pointing the `fts` font to me! It is quite an interesting font indeed!

Comment: Various options here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/89098

Answer (score 8):

Someone is bound to propose some tikz, but for the authentic hand drawn look, never forget the awesome power of ms paint:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
U_1&\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics{ra1}}&U_2&
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics{ra2}}&U_3\\
\includegraphics{ua1}&&\includegraphics{ua2}&&\includegraphics{ua3}\\
S_1&&S_2&&S_3
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although a nice Response, that is horrible! It hurt my eyes just to look at it...