# fun style cross-strike-out

Tags: ulem, cancel, strikeout

I want to cross out (strike out) words or letters in fun ways for poster-sized text for children.

`ulem` and `cancel` produce rather formal/sterile-looking cancellations, as do tikz-based combinations of diagonal or wavy lines.

Are there any existing packages that can produce something like these 'sexy' (?) strikeouts, and accurately place them over non-monospaced fonts?

[image]

Here is my MWE, and its formal result:
[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.4in,landscape] {geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,ulem}
\setmainfont{Gill Sans}[Scale=14,BoldFont={Gill Sans SemiBold}]
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{10pt}%   
\newcommand{\poster}[1]{
\vspace*{\fill}
\hspace*{\fill}#1\hspace*{\fill}
\vspace*{\fill}}
\begin{document}
\poster{merr\sout{y}ily}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very much related, perhaps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317190/handwritten-comments-and-annotations-in-margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Just overlaying an image with a transparent background

> [image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.4in,landscape] {geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern,graphicx}

\def\xout#1{\sbox0{#1}\usebox0%
\raisebox{-\dp0}{\llap{\includegraphics[totalheight=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0,width=\wd0]{crosstr.png}}}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\poster}[1]{%
\vspace*{\fill}
\hspace*{\fill}#1\hspace*{\fill}
\vspace*{\fill}}
\begin{document}\fontsize{2cm}{2.1cm}\sffamily
\poster{merr\xout{y}ily}
\end{document}
```